# Can a XML file have more than one XSD?

Tags: xml

I want to take XML file's XSD from the XML file, some websites can give you the XSD from the XML file that you uploaded. Are there any possible Schemas for a specific XML file?

Have a nice day/night

Comment: Please [edit] your question to rephrase what you are asking. It is not clear what the question/problem is. The title doesn't fit for the post content. Please read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> some websites can give you the XSD from the XML file that you uploaded.

Yes. You can abstract from XML files to an XSD. But often these files are too specific. And so you usually improve them by hand.

> Are there any possible Schemas for a specific XML file?

Also yes. There is *at least* one XSD file for each XML file.

> Can a XML file have more than one XSD?

This is (almost) always the case. You can rearrange the XSD, abstract schemes, reformulate requirements, define elements *in-place* and as *type*. There are *a lot* of possiblities.

The output from the automatically generated XSD saves some time by not having to do everything manually, but it is often not sufficient for general use.